# How to use jQuery.get() with a fully qualified URL

Tags: jquery, syntax

I am new to jQuery (and AJAX for that matter) and I am trying to get a grasp on how the get/post/ajax methods work. So I created a simple .html page that contain the following jQuery statement:

```
function myImport() {
    var url = '../rawdata.txt';
    $.get(url, function (data) {    
        $('#importedHtml').text(data);
    });
}
```

You will notice that the url var is set to a local file named 'rawdata.txt'. This file contains exactly this data:

```
0,Sun 18:32:56,0,
1,999 uS,1,
2,4561 F,0,
3,3.4,1,
4,3.3,1,
5,0.0%,0,
15,0 G,1,
16,0 G,1,
19,18.55hrs,3,
27,Setpoints,3,
28,ON:  50.16hrs,0,
29,Interlocked S,3,
30,Interlocked S,3,
31,Interlocked S,3,
```

As you can see, when the myImport() function is fired, the .get() method grabs the local rawdata.txt file, then displays the contents of the file in an html element. All this is working fine.

However, I would like to use the .get() method to grab data from a live web server (not a local file), but when I attempt to do so, I get no response from the server. I know, for sure, that the web server is up and properly responding to requests (via regular browser). So, at this point, I'm not sure if I'm using the .get() method improperly, or, something else.

For example:

The updated jQuery statement looks like this:

```
function myImport() {
    var url = 'http://173.196.155.45/taco.cgi?F0=AV&F1=4564';
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        $('#importedHtml').text(data);
    });
}
```

You'll notice that the only difference is the value of the 'url' variable. The url var is now pointing to a live web server. The url request will respond with data that looks similar to the data that exists in the 'rawdata.txt' file.

You will notice that if you visit [the live url](http://173.196.155.45/taco.cgi?F0=AV&F1=4564) that you will get a response of plain text (no HTML syntax, headers, etc - just a string of data). However, if you were to run the jQuery example, there is no content within the "data" variable of the .get() method.

Am I using the .get() method wrong in the script that contains the live url? More specifically, how can I use jQuery to grab the data that lives at [this live url](http://173.196.155.45/taco.cgi?F0=AV&F1=4564)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your HTML file is local but the data file is remote you're falling foul of "cross origin" security policies.

These require AJAX requests to be served from the same domain as the original HTML file.

To work around, either:

1. Use JSONP, which subverts the policy by using `<script>` tags, or
2. Look at supplying the [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) header from your CGI script.